# Necessary changes for Vasil hard fork

Tags: vasil-hard-fork

First of all, congratulations to IOHK team for the Vasil hard fork update!

I'm running a node and building services on top of it, do I need to make any update manually on services or node to support Vasil hard fork?

(The purpose of running the node is to list Cardano in the exchange)

Answer (score 2):

As long as you are running the latest release of the `node` (1.35.3) you are fine.